# Cannot order by in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, meta-value

I'm stuck with this issue : I'm having a custom query in which I cannot order by anything.
I want to order by a specific meta_value. But event when ordering by name, title, date etc, I still can't. What am I doing wrong ?

```
<?php 
    // Get the parent cat thanks to the page's cat slug
    $parent_cat = get_category_by_slug( $cat[1] );
    $args = array(
        'type'      => 'post',
        'child_of'  => $parent_cat->term_id
    );
    // child cats
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    // loop on the child cats to get the sub cats object
    if ($categories) {?>
    <!-- THE TITLE -->  
    <div class="text-seperator">
        <h2>Sector's programs</h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="sc_accordion">
    <?php
        foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'editorial-posts',
                'meta_key' => 'meta_post_order',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array( $value->slug ),
                        'include_children' => false
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array( 'short-description' )
                    )
                )
            );
            $program_desc_short = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
            <?php if ($program_desc_short->have_posts()) : $program_desc_short->the_post() ?>
                <?php 
                //var_dump( get_post_meta( get_the_ID() ) );
                $metas = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_post_order' );
                $order = $metas[0];
                ?>
                <li><?php echo $order ?><a class="sc_accordion-btn" href="#"><?php echo $value->name ?></a>
                <div class="sc_accordion-content"><?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit This'),'<p class="edit-link">' ,'</p>'); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo '/sectors/'.$value->slug ?>" class="btn small-btn right">Read more</a>
                </div>
            <?php endif;
            wp_reset_query();
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php 
    }                                    
?>
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: What is `meta_post_order` storing? You may need to cast it depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: `meta_post_order` is a number as a string here. I also tried with `meta_value_num` and an integer, with no success.
Actually, it seems like the order is only working in the `categories` args.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem came from the fact I was looping on categories to get the matching post. What I had to do was to get the desired categories and use it in my `$args` + some adjustments.

```
<?php 
    // Get the parent cat thanks to the page's cat slug
    $parent_cat = get_category_by_slug( $cat[1] );
    $cats_args = array(
        'type'      => 'post',
        'child_of'  => $parent_cat->term_id
    );
    // child cats
    $categories = get_categories( $cats_args );
    // loop on the child cats to get the sub cats object
    if ($categories) {
        // empty array to store cats
        $cats = array();
        // Get the cat slugs and store it in an array
        foreach ($categories as $key => $value)
            $cats[] = $value->slug;
        ?>
    <!-- THE TITLE -->  
    <div class="text-seperator">
        <h2>Sector's programs</h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="sc_accordion">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'editorial-posts',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $cats,
                    'include_children' => false
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'short-description' )
                )
            )
        );
        $program_desc_short = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if ($program_desc_short->have_posts()): while ($program_desc_short->have_posts()) : $program_desc_short->the_post() ?>
            <?php 
            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );
            $attached_category = array();
            foreach ($terms as $term)
                // in order to only get the concerned category, we check that the term is matching the cats array
                if (in_array($term->slug, $cats))
                    foreach ($term as $key => $value)
                        $attached_category[$key] = $value; 
            ?>
            <li><a class="sc_accordion-btn" href="#"><?php echo $attached_category['name'] ?></a>
            <div class="sc_accordion-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit This'),'<p class="edit-link">' ,'</p>'); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo '/sectors/'.$attached_category['slug'] ?>" class="btn small-btn right">Read more</a>
            </div>
        <?php 
        endwhile; 
        endif;
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php 
    }                                    
?>
```